# Optimal placement of assert statements to assure correctness using invariant

Tags: python, invariants, correctness, loop-invariant

I'm trying to understand invariants in programming via real examples written in Python. I'm confused about where to place `assert` statements to check for invariants.

My research has shown different patterns for where to check for invariants. For examples:

```
before the loop starts
before each iteration of the loop
after the loop terminates
```

vs

```
... // the Loop Invariant must be true here
while ( TEST CONDITION ) {
// top of the loop
...
// bottom of the loop
// the Loop Invariant must be true here
}
// Termination + Loop Invariant = Goal
```

Below I have put code for an invariant example from a Maths book. There are two version, one using a function and one not. I expect it makes no difference, but I want to be thorough.

My questions are:

- what is the minimum number of assert statemnts I need to assure program correctness, in keeping with the invariant?
- which of the assert statments in my examples are redundant?
- If there are multiple answers to the above question, which would be considered best practice?

Ideally I'd like to see a rewriting of my code to include best pratices and attention to any issues I may have overlooked in my work so far.

Any input much appreciated.

Here's the exercise:

*E2. Suppose the positive integer n is odd. First Al writes the numbers 1, 2,..., 2n on the blackboard. Then he picks any two numbers a, b, erases them, and writes, instead, |a − b|. Prove that an odd number will remain at the end.*

*Solution. Suppose S is the sum of all the numbers still on the blackboard. Initially this sum is S = 1+2+···+2n = n(2n+1), an odd number. Each step reduces S by 2 min(a, b), which is an even number. So the parity of S is an invariant. During the whole reduction process we have S ≡ 1 mod 2. Initially the parity is odd. So, it will also be odd at the end.*

```
import random

def invariant_example(n):
    xs = [x for x in range(1, 2*n+1)]
    print(xs)
    assert sum(xs) % 2 == 1
    while len(xs) >= 2:
        assert sum(xs) % 2 == 1
        a, b = random.sample(xs, 2)
        print(f"a: {a}, b: {b}, xs: {xs}")
        xs.remove(a)
        xs.remove(b)
        xs.append(abs(a - b))
        assert sum(xs) % 2 == 1
    assert sum(xs) % 2 == 1
    return xs
    
print(invariant_example(5))

n = 5
xs = [x for x in range(1, 2*n+1)]
print(xs)
assert sum(xs) % 2 == 1
while len(xs) >= 2:
    assert sum(xs) % 2 == 1
    a, b = random.sample(xs, 2)
    print(f"a: {a}, b: {b}, xs: {xs}")
    xs.remove(a)
    xs.remove(b)
    xs.append(abs(a - b))
    assert sum(xs) % 2 == 1
assert sum(xs) % 2 == 1
print(xs)
```

Comment: @TimRoberts I disagree. A loop invariant's definition states that it must be valid before, during, and after the loop. One assert function inside of the loop body is necessary, but not both.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said.  There are four asserts here.  Call them A, B, C, D in order.  You either need A and C, or you need B and D.  One inside the loop, one outside the loop at the opposite end from the one inside.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you need ***3***. One before, one during, one after. Although *technically* nothing changes in between the asserts before and after, they are always both included as a "just in case". Inside the while loop is a different scenario. Now, whether that is actually necessary is a different question. I am just following what is typically taught as a best practice, not what may be logically the best.

Comment: @Ryan The one afterwards should also include the termination condition. Maybe that supports the argument for three.

Comment: That is true. The loop exit condition should also be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only *technically* redundant `assert` statement you have is either of the ones in the loop. As in, you don't *really* need both of them.

For example:

If you have both of them, the first `assert` in the while loop will execute immediately after the second (as the code will return to the top of the loop). No values change in between those calls, so the first `assert` statement will always have the same result as the second.

Best practice would probably be to keep the `assert` at the top of the loop, to prevent code within the loop from executing if the loop invariant is violated.

EDIT: The final assert statement should also include the loop exit condition, as Kelly Bundy noted. I forgot to mention this above.

Comment: Thanks for this. Should the final assertion be `assert sum(xs) % 2 == 1 and len(xs) == 1` or the same as the exit condition for the while loop: `len(xs) >= 2` for this example please?

Comment: @RobinAndrews It should be `assert sum(xs) % 2 == 1 and len(xs) < 2`. the exit condition is the negation of the loop condition

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense. I was missing the trees for the forest a bit there.